# jsDuck javascript/jQuery recommended way to document $.trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsduck

What is the best way to document in jsDuck:

```
 $(document).trigger('myCustomEvent');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you document it as a member of jQuery class:

```
/**
 * @member jQuery
 * Some docs...
 */
trigger: function() { ... }
```